# MySQL - my View is very slow

Tags: mysql, join, view

I have 4 tables:

- **Students** `with over 7000 records`
- **Teachers** `with over 600 records`
- **Universities** `with over 30 records`
- **Lessons_Meta** `with over 10000 records`

Table **Students** columns:

```
id | student_number | name
```

Table **Teachers** columns:

```
id | teacher_number | name
```

Table **Universities** columns:

```
id | name
```

Table **Lessons_Meta** columns:

```
id | lesson_code | lesson_name | student_id | teacher_id | university_id
```

**My view is:**

```
CREATE VIEW `view_lessons` AS
SELECT
        *,
        (SELECT `name` FROM `students` WHERE `students`.`id` = `lessons_meta`.`student_id` LIMIT 1) AS "student_name",
        (SELECT `name` FROM `teachers` WHERE `teachers`.`id` = `lessons_meta`.`teacher_id` LIMIT 1) AS "teacher_name",
        (SELECT `name` FROM `universities` WHERE `universities`.`id` = `lessons_meta`.`university_id` LIMIT 1) AS "university_name"
FROM `lessons_meta`
```

**My query is:**

```
SELECT * FROM `view_lessons` LIMIT 20
```

After 20 seconds, show this query completed! How can I decrease this time load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably just need indexes.  Start with the following indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_students_id_name ON students(id, name);
CREATE INDEX idx_teachers_id_name ON teachers(id, name);
CREATE INDEX idx_universities_id_name ON universities(id, name);
```

Comment: best answer . How to find out which columns should be `INDEX`?

Comment: @mghhgm . . . The place to start is the documentation:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html.

Answer (score 1):

Change your View to this

```
CREATE VIEW `view_lessons` AS
SELECT L.*,  S.`name` AS student_name, T.`name` AS teacher_name, U.`name` AS university_name
FROM `lessons_meta` L
INNER JOIN `students` S ON S.`id` = L.`student_id`
INNER JOIN `teachers` T ON T.`id` = L.`teacher_id` 
INNER JOIN `universities` U ON U.`id` = L.`university_id`
```

- In the `lessons_meta` table, add indexes on `student_id`, `teacher_id`, `university_id`
- On all tables, ensure that the `id` column is properly indexed, normally they should be unique/PK